# Trying to animate the color of the boxes using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate, css-animations

I have 4 boxes with some color and I am trying to animate these by changing their color one after the another.The box after animating should go back to its original color and then the next box should animate.

Code being used :

```
$(function(){

$(".button").click(function(){

for (var a = [1, 2, 3, 4], i = a.length; i--; ) {
var random = a.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1)), 1)[0];

$( ".rectangle"+random.toString() ).animate({
          backgroundColor: "#aa0000",
          color: "#fff",
        },2000,function(){$(this).removeAttr('style');} );

}
});

});
```

This animates the boxes randomly but they go back to their original state only after all boxes are animated, but I want each box to animate, go back to original state then animate next box.

Comment: Could you include sample HTML as well?

Answer (score 0):

my approach using async, await

```
$(function(){
        var a = [1, 2, 3, 4]

        async function loopTheBoxes ( arr, callback ) {
            for ( let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
                await callback( arr[i] );
            }
        }

        function animateTheBoxes() {
            $(".button").click( () => {
                loopTheBoxes( a, ( index ) => {
                    return new Promise( ( resolve ) => {
                        $( ".rectangle-" + index ).animate({
                            backgroundColor: "#aa0000",
                            color: "#fff"
                          }, 2000, function() {
                              $(this).removeAttr( 'style' );
                              return resolve();
                          } );
                    });
                });
            });
        }

        animateTheBoxes();
});
```